# What do we say the base ingredient in Japanese?

Tags: word-choice

When we make okonomiyaki, for example, the base ingredient is the mix of cabbage, dough and eggs. There are many okonomiyaki topping but the base ingredient is the same.

[image]

My question is

> What do Japanese call the base ingredients?

Comment: I heard someone called it "dai" but I don't know it exactly.

Comment: `「基本材料」（きほんざいりょう）` - Standard / Base Ingredients (?) 

It's like saying all pizza has dough as a 'base'; I'm not sure there is a word for that. 

A word like the English 'stock' comes to mind but 出汁（だし） only refers to soup stock.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "dough" part of okonomiyaki is called （お好み焼きの）**生地【きじ】**. 生地 basically refers to the paste made by mixing flour and water. 生地 is also used for bread, doughnuts, pizza, udon, spaghetti, etc.

[According to Wikipedia](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%81%8A%E5%A5%BD%E3%81%BF%E7%84%BC%E3%81%8D):

> 水に溶いた小麦粉を**生地**として、野菜、肉、魚介類などを具材とし、鉄板の上で焼き上げ、ソース・マヨネーズ・青のり等の調味料をつけて食するもの

Strictly speaking, 生地 only refers to the flour and water part. At least in Tokyo, cabbage, ginger and eggs are *mixed* with the flour (rather than being topped) as the "base ingredient", but I think it's still safely called 生地 as a whole ([see this recipe](http://www.nisshin.com/entertainment/komugiko_club/meikan/05/03.html)).

In everyday conversations, **土台【どだい】** or **ベース** can also refer to the same "base" part of okonomiyaki. These words just mean "base".

If you're looking for a broader term which can be used for any dishes that can be topped (ice cream, ramen, hot dogs, curry and rice...), the ベース (noun) or プレーン (na-adjective) would refer to the "plain" one. [プレーンなお好み焼き](http://portal.nifty.com/kiji/130604160812_1.htm) would mean okonomiyaki without any fillings.

Answer (score 2):

「[基本食材]{きほんしょくざい}」 or 「基本[材料]{ざいりょう}」 would do regardless of the dish.

The word "dai" that you mentioned in the comment would be 「[台]{だい}」, which  refers to the crust part of okonomiyaki, pizza, etc.  Since you included ***cabbage***, however,  I would not use 「台」 for an answer to your question.  「台」 is just flour and water, basically.